# A scrollview in view and a tableview inside the scroll view; how do I reference it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, cell, tableview

I have a view. It is structured like this:

-View
     -Scroll view
     -TableView
         -TableView Cell

I cannot resize the table and cannot set cell's heights. The cell contents are dynamic text from json. I can get their lengths but I have a problem with referencing the table and the cells. In my header I have this:

```
@interface ListingDetailController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
```

In IB, the tableview's datasource is the Rootview, and delegated from scrollview, which itself is a delegate of the view.

I want to use the following code for example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = [[rows4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                   sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    return size.height + 10;
}
```

But it doesn't affect my table at all. Nothing changes. I can't event create the table programmatically, because it is inside a scrollview so I cannot create it with coords. If I do it goes outside the scrollview.

Would anyone recommend a way to handle this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you'd want to put a UITableView inside a UIScrollView. After all, a UITableView IS a subclass of UIScrollView, and has it's own scrolling functionality... Are you sure you need a UITableView inside a UIScrollView?

Comment: Well, the table is just a part of the whole view. Inside the scroll view, there is a photo, couple of buttons and then the table. the table is there to display the information about the venue that is being displayed. I could show the description with a text view, but I think table looks nicer; it has a description, plus couple of more details about the venue. like phone number, website, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create scroll view and tableview by programmatically. Just you have to add your tableview into scrollview. just you have to set the coordinate according to scrollview.

Comment: Thanks Hiren, creating the views (scroller, table) programmatically has made things much easier.